# How to install ffmpeg on Heroku

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord.py

I have a Python application on Heroku. How can I install ffmpeg on the app?

I tried installing it using the buildpack but I got this error:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ClientException: ffmpeg was not found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it isn't done yet, you have to create a `requirements.txt` file:

```
git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
ffmpeg
```

Then, in your heroku app, go to `settings` and, in the `buildpacks` tab, click `add buildpack` and type this:

```
https://github.com/kitcast/buildpack-ffmpeg.git
```

If you have errors related to `opus` (it can happen when you stream audio), you'll have to add this buildpack:

```
https://github.com/xrisk/heroku-opus.git
```

When everything is correctly installed, you'll have to push your code, it will install ffmpeg (and opus if you need it), and, normally, you shouldn't have this error anymore.